# Ode to the Lassitude of 88th Street

Tags: rhyme, poetry, music

> This glancing blow,
>   In freezing snow,
>   Of a cat woman,
>   In faux platinum,
>
> Dedicated to bonneted lassies,
>   Elegant ladies so classy,
>   Boy loving Mona Lisas,
>   Dressed like fashionistas,
>   Always so enticing,
>   In urban life thriving,
>
> With sneakers on my feet,
>   Patron of archivists I greet,
>   Narcissistic action is required,
>   That my beauty hath inspired,
>
> Temperatures rising outside,
>   Emergency services notified,
>   This extreme heat in the air is,
>   Making Viserion leave Daenerys,
>
> Perspiration hitting the ground,
>   Confirm to me that I am renowned,
>   In a desert all evaporated,
>   My crew remains fiscally motivated,
>
> Let the choir sopranos celebrate,<sup>*</sup>
>   Since the lassitude of 88th street will donate,<sup>*</sup>
>   Situated in our weekend location,
>   Skeptics obtain visual confirmation,<sup>**</sup>
>
> <sub>* = (x3), ** = (x6)</sub>

What in the world is this poem about?

<sub>Solvers: I know your answer can be very short but please list each line in your answer, for the benefit of others who aren't familiar with this "poem".  Thanks!</sub>

Comment: Would the [tag:knowledge] tag fit here?

Comment: Knowledge tag added, but only one phrase needs to be looked up, and the puzzle can be solved without knowing what it means.

Comment: Aha. My guess was that the answer might be something like (for example) a film actor with each line referring to one of their films, which would require a lot of trivia knowledge to be solvable. I guess it's not :-)

Comment: Fantastic translation. Needs more views and votes!

Comment: How, exactly, would you suggest this puzzle can be solved without knowing what it means?

Comment: @Bass I don't know how any pop culture / movie related puzzle would work without the solver having some knowledge of the pop culture references involved.  I mean, if some puzzle was full of Star Trek references, and you had never watched Star Trek, then you probably wouldn't be able to solve it.  For this puzzle, the source material was a recent (2014) song that spent 14 weeks at #1 on the Billboard charts (4nd longest all time), so it was pretty well known.  I admit that if you had never heard of it, you would have absolutely no chance to solve this, but not everyone can solve every puzzle.

Comment: @Bass What's ironic is that my previous puzzle was movie related, and I think solvers had a hard time because the clues were all from the 80s and 90s, i.e. before many people here were even born.  That is why I decided to use more recent pop culture references (this puzzle) but now there is the opposite effect: older solvers are not likely to be familiar with the latest pop culture but younger solvers are.  I wish I knew what the demographics of this site were.

Comment: have an upvote and a bronze badge!

Comment: Every time I think of this puzzle it makes me laugh, easily one of my favourites!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This made me laugh so much when I got it. Line by line first, answer at the bottom.

This glancing blow,
In freezing snow,
Of a cat woman,
In faux platinum,

> This hit, that ice cold
>  Michelle Pfeiffer, that white gold

Dedicated to bonneted lassies,
Elegant ladies so classy,
Boy loving Mona Lisas,
Dressed like fashionistas,
Always so enticing,
In urban life thriving,

> This one for them hood girls
>  Them good girls straight masterpieces
>  Stylin', wilin', livin' it up in the city

With sneakers on my feet,
Patron of archivists I greet,
Narcissistic action is required,
That my beauty hath inspired,

> Got Chucks on with Saint Laurent
>  Gotta kiss myself, I'm so pretty

Temperatures rising outside,
Emergency services notified,
This extreme heat in the air is,
Making Viserion leave Daenerys,

> I'm too hot (hot damn)
>  Called a police and a fireman
>  I'm too hot (hot damn)
>  Make a dragon wanna retire man

Perspiration hitting the ground,
Confirm to me that I am renowned,
In a desert all evaporated,
My crew remains fiscally motivated,

> I'm too hot (hot damn)
>  Say my name you know who I am
>  I'm too hot (hot damn)
>  And my band 'bout that money, break it down

Let the choir sopranos celebrate,*
Since the lassitude of 88th street will donate,*
Situated in our weekend location,
Skeptics obtain visual confirmation,**

> Girls hit your hallelujah (whoo)*
>  'Cause uptown funk gon' give it to you*
>  Saturday night and we in the spot
>  Don't believe me just watch

If you haven't gotten it yet, these are expertly transcribed lyrics to

> Uptown Funk by Mark Ronson ft. Bruno Mars.

Comment: Oh, this is top notch. @JS1 I love this! +1 all round!