# Ode to the Emergence of a Hikikomori

Tags: rhyme, poetry, music

Note: [Hikikomori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikikomori) is a Japanese term for "reclusive adolescents or adults who withdraw from society and seek extreme degrees of isolation and confinement.  The affected individuals refuse to leave their parents' house, do not work or go to school and isolate themselves away from society and family in a single room for a period exceeding six months."

There may be over 1 million hikikomori in Japan today, according to estimates.

> **Ode to the Emergence of a Hikikomori**
>
> The outdoor sun, it shines so bright,
>   And all my friends, are out of sight,
>   No soul for miles, to break my thoughts,
>   I'm all alone, a forlorn boss,
>
> My stormy thoughts, they match the skies,
>   I tried and failed, to keep my guise,
>   I shut them out, kept out of sight,
>   And all the while, I stayed polite,
>   I hid behind, a poker face,
>   But ran away, in full disgrace,
>
> My gloves are off, I must unload,
>   Repressed for years, I could explode,
>   I'll face my fears, be free at last,
>   The future waits, forget the past,
>
> They'll call me names, say hurtful things,
>   I'll just ignore, and spread my wings,
>   My heart's turned cold, without a doubt,
>   But I don't care, now leave, get out!

Who and what is this poem about?

Previous poem which may help you understand this one: [Ode to the Lassitude of 88th Street](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89805/ode-to-the-lassitude-of-88th-street)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a feeling that this poem:

> Is an alternate rendering of the lyrics to **Let It Go** from *Frozen*.

*The outdoor sun, it shines so bright,*
*And all my friends, are out of sight,*

> The snow glows white on the mountain tonight,
>  Not a footprint to be seen.
>  <sub>*NB At this point in the film Elsa has run away from her hometown and out into the snow - there is nobody else around in the untouched snow...*</sub>

*No soul for miles, to break my thoughts,*
*I'm all alone, a forlorn boss,*

> A kingdom of isolation,
>  And it looks like I'm the queen.

*My stormy thoughts, they match the skies,*
*I tried and failed, to keep my guise,*

> The wind is howling like this swirling storm inside.
>  Couldn't keep it in, heaven knows I've tried.

*I shut them out, kept out of sight,*
*And all the while, I stayed polite,*

> "Don't let them in", "Don't let them see";
>  "Be the good girl you always have to be".
>  <sub>*NB These are phrases Elsa was commonly told as a child; instructions about keeping her magical powers under wraps...*</sub>

*I hid behind, a poker face,*
*But ran away, in full disgrace,*

> "Conceal, don't feel, don't let them know..."
>  Well, now they know!

*My gloves are off, I must unload,*
*Repressed for years, I could explode,*
*I'll face my fears, be free at last,*
*The future waits, forget the past,*

> Let it go, let it go!
>  Can't hold it back any more.
>  Let it go, let it go.
>  Turn away and slam the door.

*They'll call me names, say hurtful things,*
*I'll just ignore, and spread my wings,*
*My heart's turned cold, without a doubt,*
*But I don't care, now leave, get out!*

> I don't care what they're going to say.
>  Let the storm rage on,
>  The cold never bothered me anyway...

As for the title:

> The given definition of 'Hikikomori' ("reclusive adolescents or adults who withdraw from society and seek extreme degrees of isolation and confinement") - this perfectly describes **Queen Elsa**, the singer of this song!

I am positive this is correct...

> As the father of a *Frozen*-obsessed three-year old girl, I have heard these lyrics SO MANY TIMES! It all clicks together beautifully - nice puzzle :)

Comment: I have a feeling that in a few days your daughter will be obsessed with a new song, whatever it may be.

Comment: @JS1 I fear you may be very much correct!

Comment: @JS1 ^ Yep, you were right...!